# Unable to convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.myApp.model.NoticeModel

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime database,but i am getting this error when new child is added in database.

"Process: com.example.myApp, PID: 12458                                                                                                    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.myApp.model.NoticeModel"

This is my database structure

```
{
  "newsNotices": {
    "dateChanged": {
      "lastUpdated": "01 January 2024 14:19:18"
    },
    "eventItem": {
      "-NmSeiOMCcp1qeQmj7Mu": {
        "id": 1703452272,
        "notice": {
          "name": "Event Title",
          "sub_list": [
            {
              "link": "https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/basic-link-1.pdf",
              "name": "Poster"
            },
            {
              "link": "https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/basic-link-1.pdf",
              "name": "Brochure"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "-NmSelGBrZqTB2kFPHC4": {
        "id": 1703452284,
        "notice": {
          "link": "https://www.antennahouse.com/hubfs/xsl-fo-sample/pdf/basic-link-1.pdf",
          "name": "Workshop link"
        }
      }
    },
    "running_time": {
      "lastRun": 1704191244
    }
  }
}
```

In short:- I am fetching the "eventItems". For each item there are two nods. "id" and "notice" and in one notice/item it can be "name & link" or "name & sublist", then sublist can have "name & link".

these are my data classes which i am using to retrieve data from firebase

```
data class NoticeModel(
    var id: Long?=null,
    var notice: newsModel? = null
)
data class newsModel(
    var link: String? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var sub_list: List<SubList?>? = null
)
data class SubList(
    val link: String? = null,
    val name: String? =null
)
```

This is my resporitory class,

```
class MainRepository {
    private val database = Firebase.database

    fun fetchNews(noticeLiveData: MutableLiveData<Response<List<NoticeModel>>>, path: String) {
//path is passed through viewModel
        val newsReference = database.getReference(path)
        newsReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val newsItemList = mutableListOf<NoticeModel>()
                for (ds in snapshot.children) {
                    val noticeModel = ds.getValue(NoticeModel::class.java)
                    if (noticeModel != null) {
                        newsItemList.add(noticeModel)
                    }
                }
                noticeLiveData.postValue(Response.Success(newsItemList))
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                noticeLiveData.postValue(Response.Error("Some error occurred")) }
        })
    }
}
```

My viewModel class

```
class EventsViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val repository = MainRepository()
    private val _latestEventsLiveData = MutableLiveData<Response<List<NoticeModel>>>()
    val latestEventsLiveData: LiveData<Response<List<NoticeModel>>> = _latestEventsLiveData

    private val path = "/newsNotices/eventItem"


    fun fetchLatestNews() {
        repository.fetchNews(_latestEventsLiveData, path)
    }
}
```

When i fetch normally it works successfully. But when a child is get added it gives me this error and app crashes. I don't know what's happening. I am new to firebase & i looked in some solutions but unable to resolve.

Comment: You must have scenario-based data class. Assign the ```notice``` node to type ```Any``` and decide whether it is sub-list type or other on a runtime basis.

Comment: What's the value of `path` inside `.getReference(path)`? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i have added my viewModel code from there firebase database path is passed. I am passing through viewModel because i have several viewmodels with different paths. inside newNotices there are several nodes & eventItem is one of those.

Comment: I cannot see any `newsNotices` nodes in your database. Are you sure that is present?

Comment: @AlexMamo i have updated my database Structure in question. Can you please look into it.